# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Trying to install Ruby 2.0, but gnome-session-bin seems to be half installed

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, updates, dpkg

I cannot install any packages, the problem started when I tried to install the *ruby2.0*. Before, `apt-get` was installing everything. But now, every package returns this error:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-bin (--configure):
 package gnome-session-bin is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
```

I've tried also

```
sudo dpkg gnome-session-bin --configure

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-bin (--configure):
 package gnome-session-bin is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-session-bin
```

I've already cleaned my `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` directory and

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Doesn't work at all. 
What is a half installed package? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved using synaptic. I've reinstalled the package gnome-session-bin and the system is running ok